# Determine if word from alteration list exists and set next condition accordingly

Tags: c#, regex

A not-so-clear title, I know...

Here is what I'm looking for in RegEx (C#):
I have two alteration lists, say (aa|bb) & (xx|yy).
I want to set the second list's prefix according to the whether there is an item from the first list before it.

For example, if there is a string from the first list, then the second list should be prefixed by j or p.

If not - it should be prefixed by o or t.

Some samples:

```
aa jxx <- Match
aa pyy <- Match
bb nxx <- Does not match
oxx <- Match
jxx <- Does not match
```

How can I achieve that in RegEx?

Thanks!

Comment: This is some rather hefty logic for a regex and I belive that it would be better to not use regex to perform such an operation. I am sure someone will solve it but consider other options perhaps for readability and maintainability.

Comment: @karl-henrik: do you really understand what OP wants? I'm impressed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you pay some attention to what he describes, it's not that difficult. He actually "wrote" the RegEx himself - in words. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
(?:[ot](xx|yy))|(?:(aa|bb)\s[jp](xx|yy))
```

**Demo :**

http://regex101.com/r/hH0zO6

---

*Hint :* All I did was to "translate" your specification into regex. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^((aa|bb)\s+[jp](xx|yy))|([ot](xx|yy))$
```

Basically it has two main regex condition separated by a pipe(`|`). `((aa|bb)\s+[jp](xx|yy))` and `([ot](xx|yy))`